# I need to centered element in a form inline

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

This is my form inline:

```
<form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="font-size:40px">BOOKMARK</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Privacy</label>
        <div>
            <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_checked">
                <option select value="tutti">Tutti</option>
                <option value="pubblica">Pubblica</option>
                <option value="privata">Privata</option>
                <option value="collaborativa">Collaborativa</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Categoria</label>
        <div>
            <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_bookmarked_cheked"></select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <i class="fa fa-cog fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that the element are not centered/aligned. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Where is the CSS that attempts to center things?

Comment: please post the css as well and please specify which element you want centered.

Comment: please update more details

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to center the whole inline form, the page below demonstrates a centered inline form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>centered inline form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .form-inline
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label style="font-size:40px">BOOKMARK</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Privacy</label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_checked">
                    <option select value="tutti">Tutti</option>
                    <option value="pubblica">Pubblica</option>
                    <option value="privata">Privata</option>
                    <option value="collaborativa">Collaborativa</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Categoria</label>
            <div>
                <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_bookmarked_cheked"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <i class="fa fa-cog fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please explain what you did. Also consider writing a snippet - lastly it does not look very good

Comment: @mplungjan, I'm assuming poopp wanted to make the whole inline form center aligned. It doesn't look very good though, indeed. :D

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to align your form. Since you are using twitter bootstrap, you can use the grid system:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  //Your markup

  </div> 
</div>
```

What this does is it puts your content on 8/12 of the screen, and it centers it by offsetting it on the left by 2/12. Hope this helps, and from now on try to use the grid system, it is one of boostraps' very powerful tools!

Answer (score 0):

You can center all the child elements of your `form`, using CSS `Flexbox`:

```css
.form-inline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.form-inline div {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.form-inline div:first-of-type label {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>BOOKMARK</label>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Privacy:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_checked">
      <option select value="tutti">Tutti</option>
      <option value="pubblica">Pubblica</option>
      <option value="privata">Privata</option>
      <option value="collaborativa">Collaborativa</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Categoria:</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="seleziona_bookmarked_cheked"></select>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><i class="fa fa-cog fa-1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>

</form>
```